# How to write Python if/then statement using information from two fields in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, if-else

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. I create a new field of type short integer in the Attribute Table. My new field is named CIPOT and I want to populate it with values from the field CI, but only if values in field Z = 100, otherwise I want CIPOT to equal zero.

My Python script:

```
def NumValue( CI ):

  if (Z == 100):
    return CI
  else:  return 0

NumValue(!CI! )
```

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I am getting an error message that global name 'Z' in not defined.

Comment: You need to pass in a variable into your function for Z.  `def NumValue(CI, Z):`

`NumValue(!CI!, !Z!)

Comment: !ci! If !z!==100 else 0 will work without block.

Comment: felixIP: that doesn't work. I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

As @NathanW has [commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312695/how-to-write-python-if-then-statement-using-information-from-two-fields-in-field/312700#comment507620_312695), you have passed the value of your `CI` field to your function using `defNumValue(CI):`, but have not passed the value of the `Z` field.

You can pass the `Z` value by just adding it to your function variables

```
def NumValue(CI, Z):
    if (Z == 100):
        return CI
    else:  return 0
```

Expression:

```
NumValue(!CI!, !Z!)
```